# How to censor words in python

Tags: python

I know I'm a newbie in programming but I'd like to write a Python script to censor some data.

My inputfile in structured like this:

```
username:password
username:p4ssw0rd
mail:pa3386
```

I need to censor all characters after the first 2-3 character right after the colon ":"

The results should be something like this:

```
username:pass****
username:p4ss**
mail:pa88***
```

Is there a way to do this?

I've been struggling a lot and tried with strip or split but i'm not able to get this to work...

```
f = open("myfile.txt",'r')

#result = [x.strip() for x in my_string.split(',')]
strings = f.read().strip()

print(strings)

targets = strings.split(':')

print(targets)

for x in range(len(strings)):
    strings[x].strip()

print(strings)

lines = f.read().split('\n')

length = len(lines)
print(length)
for x in range(length):
    print(strings[x])
```

Comment: why dont u do find. It will give you the position. Then use +n to mask the rest of the data

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will work:

```py
f = open("myfile.txt", 'r')

lines = f.read().split('\n') # Get all lines of files (pairs of `key: value`)
result = [] # Result of "censoring", will be same format as input

for i in lines: # Loop each line
  data = i.split(':') # Split, data[0] is a key and data[1] is a value (what we need to censor)
  result.append(data[0] + ':' + data[1][0:3] + '***') # Censor, leaving only three first characters
  # TODO: Handle situations when value is less when 3 symbols

final = '\n'.join(result); # Join lines together

# TODO: Write `final` to file or do something with it
```

#### What was missing in original code?

```py
f = open("myfile.txt",'r')

strings = f.read().strip() # All contents of file, removed extra spaces at end and at start
targets = strings.split(':') # From file:
                             # a:b
                             # c:d
                             # Will get ['a', 'b\nc', 'd']

for x in range(len(strings)): # Loop each character in input file (remember `strings` is .read().split())
    strings[x].strip() # Nothing is did at this cycle, .strip() just returns copy

# For what was `strings` and `targets` defined? 

lines = f.read().split('\n') # Get all lines in the file

# Print file line-by-line
lenght = len(lines)
print(lenght)
for x in range(lenght):
    print(strings[x])
```

So, in original code, all the algorithm was missing. I could not explain anything instead of "Algorithm was missing". Sorry.

Comment: All the algorithm was actually missing beacause i posted only my tests. Thanks to your help now i managed to solve it like this: for i in lines:
  data = i.split(':') 
  lenght = len(data[1])
  if lenght<3:
   result.append(data[0] + ':' + data[1][0:lenght] + '***') # Censor, leaving only three first characters
  else: 
   result.append(data[0] + ':' + data[1][0:3] + '***') # Censor from the last character and above  
final = '\n'.join(result);

Answer (score -1):

I am using this. It will solve your problem too

```
    text=raw_input("Enter your text: ").lower()
    word=raw_input("Choose a word from the previously entered text: ").lower()
    def censor(text,word):
        t=text.split()
        n=[]
        for i in t:
            if(i==word):
                n.append("*"*len(word))
            else:
                n.append(i)
        return " ".join(n)
    print censor(text,word)
```